# Ambari UI not showing versions in cluster installation

Tags: hadoop, ambari, hdp

I've successfully installed Ambari server/agent 2.7.5 on my Centos 7 machine. Now i am facing an issue while installing a cluster in the install wizard at the "Select version" step. I have no versions showing in my dropdown. What can be the issue?

ps: see screenshots

[my content in /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MASbk.png)

[install wizard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZxkl.png)

Comment: Unclear how you started Ambari, but "HDP" doesn't really exist anymore, so no Ambari Stacks including it aren't publicly available

Comment: @OneCricketeer  So this means that i cannot use it even though i installed it? How can i setup a cluster if that's the case ?

Comment: You cannot install HDP, no, or at least shouldn't because it's no longer supported... But that doesn't prevent you from installing other Ambari stacks like BigTop. Otherwise, you'll need to pay Cloudera and create an account with them to download their stuff

Answer (score 1):

Now that ambari has come back to life, this conversation is relevant despite other stack members feels.  Additionally 100s if not 1000s of companies are still using free open source ambari w/ free open source HDP.

When you are building ambari 2.7.5 from source,  you need to feed it a stack.  HDP was one of them, that is no NLA unless you copied it.

The last free HDP repos you need are found here:

https://www.makeopensourcegreatagain.com/rpms/

And you can find instructions about how to use these here:

https://github.com/steven-matison/dfhz_ddp_mpack

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

Copy HDP 3.0 and 3.1 Stack to `/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/hdp`, and then restart ambari-server

Step 2:

After clicking the "Add Version" button，for details, please refer to https://www.yuque.com/create17/mxswdh/pqrb9q#tsdHa

For the premise, you need to have an HDP-related RPM package.